# How to take a screenshot with the actual pointer icon?

Tags: mouse, cursor, screenshot

Normal keyboard shortcuts for screenshots like Ctrl+Print_Screen do not include the pointer in the image at all.

Special applications like Take Screenshot may offer an effect option to include the pointer in the image but the pointer icon seems always to be saved as an arrow. I.e. even if the screenshot is taken while grabbing a window and the screen is displaying the hand-pointer the saved image nevertheless has the arrow-pointer.

How to take a screenshot with the actual pointer icon?

Comment: On 14.04, with `gnome-screenshot-3.10.1-0ubuntu1`, using the command `gnome-screenshot -p -d 5` (include pointer, delay 5 seconds), I could take this: http://imgur.com/BeGhVOp. This was done over VNC, and I couldn't even see whether the pointer had changed when I dragged.

Comment: @muru, I can see that your gnome-screenshot saved the pointer icon correctly. I wonder is the different behaviour due to different desktop environment. I run 14.10 with unity 7.3.1 and also with gnome-screenshot-3.10.1-0ubuntu1.

Comment: `xfce4-screenshooter` will also capture the mouse pointer as a pointing finger if that's what the pointer is at the time. It's in the software center.

Comment: Can you explain what Ctrl+Print_Screen is supposed to do on your system?

Answer (score 26):

This is the update version of Screenshot application. Here just check the mark on of include pointer.

[image: Screenshot application]

Comment: This worked for one time when I pressed 'Take Screenshot' button in this window. However, it does not seem to remember the setting for later invocation by the 'PrtSc' key on a keyboard. Is there any way to save the setting?

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 16.10, this does not answer the question. This program doesn’t capture the “actual pointer icon” as requested, but instead shows a pointing arrow where the cursor was, even if the cursor was a hand or a resize arrow. The version I’m using is `gnome-screenshot` 3.22.0, and I’m on the default Unity desktop environment.

Comment: It's funny that to include the pointer I need to check it and click on Take Screenshot, the pointer will always be there. I needed to take a screenshot of a hover action because it's weird for the client without a pointer. I took the screenshot by leaving the point hover over the element, ctrl + tab to Screenshot and hit Enter. Voila !

Comment: In the new version at least, if you Select area to grab (now named "Selection" with a big button), Include pointer (now named Show Pointer) is greyed out, and it's as if it was always off. I always use Shutter when I need a precise capture including the cursor.

Comment: I select show pointer and it still doesn't show up in the image.

Answer (score 11):

Open a terminal window and issue the following command:

```
gnome-screenshot -p
```

to include the pointer. Or, if you need a few seconds after issuing the command in order to place the pointer/focus where you want it, try

```
sleep 5 && gnome-screenshot -p
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding a previous comment from @dk-bose, xfce4-screenshooter does have an option to capture the mouse pointer.

Using xubuntu-14.04, pressing PrintScreen doesn't capture the mouse pointer, you have to start xfce4-screenshooter and enable the **Capture the mouse pointer** option before doing the capture.

[image: xfce4-screenshooter settings]

Comment: Awesome ! Works from Lubuntu too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

- Open system settings, click on keyboard, then go to the shortcuts tab.
- On the side panel, click on Screenshots.
- Click "Take a screenshot" and press the backspace key to clear (disable) it.
- Next, click the "+" sign at the bottom left side. Type any name for the "name" box (I used the same "Take a screenshot" name from before).
- Type `gnome-screenshot -p` for the "command" box.
- Click "Apply".
- On the newly created shortcut, click where it says "Disabled" and press the "Print_Screen" button, or whichever key combo you want, and voila!
- Try it out and make sure it works!

Comment: This describes how to change the default screenshot action to include the mouse pointer which isn't what OP asked for. The core of the solution is the same as [CPBL’s answer](/a/842123/175814).

Comment: And it captures the actual pointer instead of substituting the default pointer like gnome-screenshot does.

Answer (score 0):

Try [vokoscreen](https://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html).

To install, download the file from the vokoscreen [website](https://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html), extract it, go into the Ubuntu folder, choose your version, and then your architecture.

Once that is done, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the correct folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name.deb>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe that vokoscreen recording as well as many other screen recorders can capture the pointer icon as it is displayed on the screen but I want something light, simple and robust.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu Mate 20.04, and I have no `gnome-screenshot -p` command, and I wanted to get actual mouse cursor in screenshots without installing `gnome-screenshot`.

I eventually found a recommendation in https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/screenshot-ubuntu/ to use GIMP, which I already had installed ("vanilla" deb install from the Ubuntu 20.04 repos); and can confirm that it works: in GIMP, go to File/Create/Screenshot, and you'll get this dialog window:

[image: gimp screenshot]

Then I was able to take a screenshot of Audacity, with the mouse course positioned on a boundary of a selection, which makes the mouse cursor icon change:

[image: audacity screenshot with mouse pointer]

... and the change mouse cursor icon is captured on the screenshot - which is exactly what I needed.

Do note that the mouse pointer ends up as a separate layer:

[image: gimp layer mouse pointer]

... so you'll want to do Image/Flatten Image, before being able to copy/paste the desired screenshot other places (like, say, here).