# Take a screenshot of a region while including the cursor

Tags: cursor, screenshot

I'm trying to set it so that when I hit Shift + PrtSc it will take a screenshot of a region while including the current cursor.

I've seen instructions to set a custom shortcut, e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/955968/1070414 to call a command as from the terminal.

Using a terminal, I can take a screenshot of the entire screen, including the cursor, with `gnome-screenshot -p`.

And I can take a screenshot of a region using `gnome-screenshot -a`.

But when I mix them, i.e. `gnome-screenshot -a -p` or `gnome-screenshot -p -a` I get a screenshot of a region, but without the cursor.

Is there some way to set it so that gnome-screenshot will give me a screenshot of a region, and include the cursor, or would I need to use a different program?

---

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with gnome-screenshot 3.25.0

Comment: Hope you solve this.  Not familiar with it. BUT I use shutter in Kubuntu and it gives you all those options and tons more.

Comment: I think region is specified by mouse cursor.. so when you select a region.. your cursor is at a corner which is not in the region..

Comment: Is the selected region constant or do you need to select it each time?

Comment: @DKBose I would need to select it each time. My primary use would be taking screenshots of parts of webpages for customer support, often with the cursor over a link, or with a menu open.

Comment: It seems that the cursor (mouse pointer) is being asked to do two distinct things at the same time.

Comment: On my Windows machine at work I get this behaviour using a program called "Greenshot".