# How to disable mouse pointer/courser on selective screenshot using Ctrl + Shift + PrtSc hotkey

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, screenshot

Many times when I take a selective screenshot using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, my mouse pointer in included, even though my mouse pointer is outside the selected area

- I have a preinstalled "screenshot" tool, thought I am not sure if it is being used for the shortcut or not and the option is grayed out for selective screenshots.

[image]

- I looked at this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545430/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-the-actual-pointer-icon) but the options where not sufficient and some seem to be outdated.

So is there any option to disable showing the mouse pointer for a selective screenshots?

Btw I am on Ubuntu 21.10

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically noticed that the cursor is within picture when I move the cursor after pressing the hotkeys into the picture again

This is due to a delay when the screenshot is taken. I thought it would take the screenshot "immediately" after pressing.

so it does not solve the question on how to disable it but it solves my problem of cursor appearing withing the selected window